# Problems with rhohat in R - Distribution of archaeological finds in relation to environmental factors

Tags: r, spatstat

I am currently working with metal axe heads from Denmark, England/Wales and the Netherlands, which I have analysed with the rhohat function in R. The spatial covariates I have employed are soil type, soil texture, soil pH, land cover and a shapefile containing estimated preservation capacity across Europe (Source: https://esdac.jrc.ec.europa.eu/content/maps-related-predicting-preservation-cultural-artefacts-and-buried-materials-soils-eu-0). This is my code (if my spatial covariate is a shapefile):

```
r <- raster(ncol=180, nrow=180)

extent(r) <- extent(soil)

soiltype_raster <- rasterize(soil, r, 'FAO85LV1')

soiltype_im <- as.im(soiltype_raster)

plot(soiltype_im)
plot(axeheads, add=TRUE)

soiltype_dk <- rhohat(axeheads.pp, soiltype_im)

plot(soiltype_dk)
```

The values of my rhohat graphs and the graphs themselves don't make alot of sense, see 
[Rhohat of English and Welsh metal axe heads in relation to land cover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgpke.png), [Rhohat of Danish metal axe heads in relation to land cover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mawp.png) or [Rhohat of English and Welsh metal axe heads in relation to soil texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUJQC.png). The spatial covariate land cover is a three-digit numerical value (i.e. 111=Discontinuous urban fabric), whereas soil texture is a numerical value between 1-5 (coarse to fine, with additional values 0=no information and 9=no mineral texture).

What could be causing my funky-looking graphs that do not seem to correspond with the information I have extracted in QGIS? What are the values on the Y-axis? Are there any other functions that could be useful for investigating the relation between the distribution of finds and environmental factors? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This looks weird. Can you provide a fully reproducible example with data and code?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about the function `rhohat` in the R package `spatstat` (this is not part of the base R system!)

The help file for `rhohat` says that the covariate must have numerical values. In your example, the covariates are more like categorical values that are encoded as numerical values. For example, 111 means discontinuous urban fabric: what do 110 and 112 mean, and is 111 halfway between them?

For this kind of data you would be better advised to convert the covariates to categorical (`factor`) values and use raw estimates of intensity:

```
soiltype_im <- eval.im(factor(soiltype_im))
soiltype_tess <- tess(image=soiltype_im)
soiltype_count <- quadratcount(axeheads.pp, tess=soiltype_tess)
soiltype_inten <- intensity(soiltype_count)
```

The last result will be a table telling you the average number of axeheads per unit area in each type of soil. (`rhohat` gives a similar calculation but assumes that the covariate is continuously-varying, which does not apply in your example)

Comment: I did not realise that categorical values could be encoded as numerical values, that explains a lot. Yes, apart from my soil pH, I know realise that all my values are categorical (i.e. 111 = Continuous urban fabric, 112 = Discontinuous urban fabric, 121 = Industrial or commercial units). Thank you for the suggestion of alternative method, I will try this out. Do I first convert the values to factor and then transform the shapefiles to 'im' object? Thank you again.